QueryObject.ComputeSignedDistanceToPoint with Expression type
I'm trying to include a signed distance constraint/cost in my MathematicalProgram for obstacle avoidance of some predetermined obstacles.
I understand from these questions that the correct way to do it is probably to wrap everything in a MultibodyPlant.  Unfortunately, I lacked the foresight to do this, hence what I have right now is just a point in the form of an Expression that I wish to evaluate the signed distance to a set of AnchoredGeometry in the SceneGraph.
My current attempt is as follows:
scene_graph = SceneGraph()
source_id = scene_graph.RegisterSource()
scene_graph.RegisterAnchoredGeometry(source_id, GeometryInstance(...))
query_object = scene_graph.get_query_output_port().Eval(
    scene_graph.CreateDefaultContext()
)
...
point = ... # array([<Expression "x(0,0)">, <Expression "x(0,1)">,  <Expression "x(0,2)">], dtype=object)

prog.AddConstraint(
    query_object.ComputeSignedDistanceToPoint(point)
    >= desired_distance
)

Unfortunately, this gives me the error
TypeError: ComputeSignedDistanceToPoint(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: pydrake.geometry.QueryObject, p_WQ: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[3, 1]], threshold: float = inf) -> List[drake::geometry::SignedDistanceToPoint<double>]

Invoked with: <pydrake.geometry.QueryObject object at 0x71897253d030>, array([<Expression "x(0,0)">, <Expression "x(0,1)">,
       <Expression "x(0,2)">], dtype=object)

Is there any way to get this to work?

Unfortunately SceneGraph doesn't support symbolic computation in the distance query (typically the distance is computed numerically through FCL, which doesn't support Drake's symbolic expression).
On the other hand, we have DistanceConstraint class which put lower/upper bounds on the distance between a pair of geometries. Could you use this constraint? One pair of the geometry could be a sphere with a tiny radius (hence a point).
You mentioned issue with MultibodyPlant. Do you not have MultibodyPlant in this problem, but only have a SceneGraph?

No I do not have a MultibodyPlant in this problem.  I originally thought I'd be able to formulate the MP manually until I faced this problem of specifying the collision avoidance constraints.  Does the DistanceConstraint use the SceneGraph in a way that avoids symbolic computation when calculating the gradients?  I was hoping I'd be able to mimic that manually.

DistanceConstraint does use SceneGraph and avoids symbolic computation. If you only have SceneGraph but no MultibodyPlant, you can refer to the implementation of DistanceConstraint to implement your own constraint. The reason why DistanceConstraint relies on MultibodyPlant is because we need it for Jacobian computation.

I was able to mimic the behavior by manually specifying the constraint and gradients following this tutorial.
What I did was first create a autodiff-compatible function that converts my decision variables into my point in question.
def sample_func(decision_vars):
    ...
    return sample_point

Then I created a autodiff-compatible distance-to-obstacle function (using numerical gradients)
# col is the collision object used for the sample point.
def dist_to_obstacle_expr(x, obstacle, sample_func, col):
    if x.dtype == float:
        sample = sample_func(x)
        return obstacle.dist(sample, col)
    else:
        x_value = ExtractValue(x).flatten()
        x_grad = ExtractGradient(x)

        sample = sample_func(x_value)
        # Compute the constraint and approximate gradient
        # We are using central differencing here as the `option` argument.
        y_value = obstacle.dist(sample, col)
        y_grad = (
            ComputeNumericalGradient(
                lambda val: obstacle.dist(sample_func(val), col),
                x_value,
                option=NumericalGradientOption(NumericalGradientMethod.kCentral),
            )
            @ x_grad
        )

        # Return the new AutoDiffXd object with the constraint and gradient
        return InitializeAutoDiff(y_value, y_grad)

Here, obbstacle.dist computes numerically the distance between a point and my obstacle (e.g. using PyBullet**)
    def dist(self, sample, col):
        pts = p.getClosestPoints(
            bodyA=-1,
            bodyB=-1,
            distance=100,
            collisionShapeA=col,
            collisionShapePositionA=sample,
            collisionShapeB=self.cylinder_col,
            collisionShapePositionB=self.center,
        )
        d = pts[0][8]
        return np.array([d])

These were then combined using a Gamma function and exponentially smoothed hinge loss function as referenced in Whole-body Motion Planning with
Centroidal Dynamics and Full Kinematics and from here
def gamma_fn(x):
    if x.dtype == float:
        ret = 0.0
    else:
        ret = AutoDiffXd(0.0)
    for obs in obstacles:
        ret += exponentially_smoothed_hinge_loss_function(
        dist_to_obstacle_expr(x, obstacle, sample_func, col)
    return np.array([ret]) # must return np array
    
def exponentially_smoothed_hinge_loss_function(x):
    if x.dtype == float:
        if x >= 0.0:
            return 0.0
        else:
            return -x * math.exp(1.0 / x)
    else:
        x_value = ExtractValue(x).flatten()
        x_grad = ExtractGradient(x)

        if x_value >= 0.0:
            y_value = 0.0
            return AutoDiffXd(y_value)
        else:
            exp_one_over_x = math.exp(1.0 / x_value)
            y_value = -x_value * exp_one_over_x
            y_grad = (-exp_one_over_x + exp_one_over_x / x_value) @ x_grad
            return AutoDiffXd(y_value, y_grad)

This allows me to create the constraint with
prog.AddConstraint(gamma_fn,
            lb=np.array([0.0]),
            ub=np.array([0.0]),
            vars=x)

** I've evaluated distance3d, PyBullet and FCL.  PyBullet seems to outperform distance3d while FCL doesn't provide signed distances which we need.
